# html2Canvas screenshot of div with appended jquery nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, html2canvas

I want to take a screenshot of a `<div>` with html2canvas and download it. The problem is that I use `.append` to append some images via jQuery to the div.

```
$("#mydiv").append("<img src=picture1.png id=okboomer></img>");
```

The download result is always just an empty image because html2canvas seems to ignore those appended nodes. How could I fix this?

Stupid fix I found out:

```
var screenshotarea = document.body;
```

If I screenshot the whole body my images are there, in the downloaded pic.png. However I don't want to screenshot the whole page, just the area of the image which is appended to the `<div>`.

User Download of the canvas:

```
var körper = document.getElementById("mydiv");

html2canvas(körper,{allowTaint : false}).then(function(canvas) {

                var link = document.createElement("a");
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.download = "html_image.png";
                link.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                link.target = '_blank';
                link.click();
```

Comment: Just a guess, but it may be because the HTML you're adding is invalid. Try this instead: `$("#mydiv").append('<img src="picture1.png" id="okboomer" />');`

Comment: `If I screenshot the whole body my images are there` in that case there may be an issue with how you target the div to print in the canvas. Can you please add more relevant parts of your code showing how you use HTML2Canvas

Comment: $("#mydiv").append('<img src="picture1.png" id="okboomer" />'); this didn't changed anything.

I added some of my code (the canvas gets downloaded) to my question.